# Collect YouTube video views and upload date using xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I am sorry I am a newbie to python it would be helpful if some1 know how to resolve it.

I got a strange result when I tried to get the video views and the upload date of a list of videos from YouTube.

```
0 : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXXXXXX <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="XXXXXXXXXXX", element="XXXXXXXXXXX")> <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="XXXXXXXXXXX", element="XXXXXXXXXXX")> <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="XXXXXXXXXXX", element="XXXXXXXXXXX")>
```

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/XXX/chromedriver.exe')

dataset = pd.read_csv(r"C:\XXXX.csv", skiprows=0)
dataset.head()

for index, row in dataset[0:1].iterrows():
    try:
        links = str(dataset.loc[index,'youtube_link'])
        driver.get(links)
        time.sleep(3)
        print(index, ":", links, driver.find_element_by_xpath("//meta[@itemprop='name']"),driver.find_element_by_xpath("//meta[@itemprop='uploadDate']"),driver.find_element_by_xpath("//meta[@itemprop='interactionCount']"))
    except: 
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

`driver.find_element_by_xpath()` will return the `webelement` and which is returning as expected.

If you need to return `text` of the element then you need to add `.text` with the element.

So code will be

```
print(index, ":", links, driver.find_element_by_xpath("//meta[@itemprop='name']").text,driver.find_element_by_xpath("//meta[@itemprop='uploadDate']").text,driver.find_element_by_xpath("//meta[@itemprop='interactionCount']").text)
```

**Update:**

You need to fetch the `get_attribute("content")` attribute of the element.

```
print(index, ":", links, driver.find_element_by_xpath("//meta[@itemprop='name']").text,driver.find_element_by_xpath("//meta[@itemprop='uploadDate']").get_attribute("content"),driver.find_element_by_xpath("//meta[@itemprop='interactionCount']").get_attribute("content"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, however the result I got now is 
0 : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXXXXXX   

It seems I am not getting the views and the upload date from YouTube. :S
Did I missed out something?

Comment: @Ben, can you please post the html of element? I need to check the element may be hidden on the page or may be other attributes?

Comment: Sure, thanks mate!

<meta itemprop="uploadDate" content="2022-04-13">
<meta itemprop="interactionCount" content="21635">

Comment: @Ben : Check my updated answer.